# git push to multiple remote repositories at once in Egit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, git-push, eclipse-kepler

Looking some like [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)  in egit.

When I right click on git repository and try to push(using **Push branch...**) I can only push to a single remote repository at a time.

Is there way to push all the changes to all the available remote repositories at once?

Egit version: 3.2.0.201312181205-r
Eclipse: Kepler Service Release 2

Answer (score 1):

No, this is currently (as of EGit 3.3) not implemented.